# Centos stopped responding

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I've CentOS 6.4 on my system. It suddenly stopped responding with the following messages in /var/log/messages

```
Jun 25 21:56:18 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs (sdg1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:934:  inode #2: comm updatedb: reading directory lblock 0
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs (sdc1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdc1): ext4_find_entry:934: inode #2: comm updatedb: reading directory lblock 0
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:934: inode #2: comm updatedb: reading directory lblock 0
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:934: inode #2: comm updatedb: reading directory lblock 0
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:934: inode #2: comm updatedb: reading directory lblock 0
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Jun 26 04:28:12 ct-0094 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_find_entry:934: inode #2: comm updatedb: reading directory lblock 0
```

What might be the issues here? I'm a novice in this kind of stuff, so any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message indicates a problem on the filesystems on your drive /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdc1

The question is what caused this problem ?  It could be a filesystem corruption, although as the problem is happening on both partitions it may be a driver or motherboard fault.   (You have not provided enough information to ascertain if this is likely).

You need to be aware that your data is at risk - if its still readable, the first thing to do is attempt to get as much as you can onto another drive.   Once you have done this, you may want to try rebooting your computer (power it off fully, then power on), and see if it fixes itself.

Another possibility is someone has been trying to access the drives directly when they are raided, and this has caused data corruption.  (It would seem very co-incidental that sdb and sdc would both have an error at the same place !)

Comment: Thanks @davidgo, I had to hard reboot the system to get it working. Luckily, I got the data back. Now I'm trying to investigate further.

Comment: I'm really pleased you got the data back.